# Checking if word file is already open vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Before opening a Word file, I want to check if this file is already open. (More word files are open at the same time)
The main sub calls this function to tell me if it's open or not.

```
Function FileInWdOpen(DokName As String) As Boolean                 

    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document

    On Error Resume Next                                            
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND                                     

    If wd Is Nothing Then                                           
        FileInWdOpen = False
    End If

    For Each wDoc In wd.Documents        'should check for every open word file but doesn't do that                         
        If wDoc.Name = DokName Then      'checks if this file is named like the one I want to check if its open or not                           
            FileInWdOpen = True
            Exit Function                                           
        End If
    Next                                                            

    FileInWdOpen = False                                            

    Exit Function

NO_WORD_FOUND:       

    FileInWdOpen = False                                            

End Function
```

This code works out well when only one word file is open. If two or more files are open, the script don't work.

The problem is that the for loop only checks the first file that is open.

I don't understand why it don't check all open files.
I thought it's possible to access all Documents with:

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application                 'sets an var for the Word Application
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")   'give the var an obj, in this case the Word Application

Dim WordDoc As Word.Document                    'sets an var for the singel Word Documents
For Each WordDoc In WordApp.Documents           'for each Document in Dokuments
    'code
Next
```

So why only the first document gets attention?

Comment: You don't need the loop.  Just try assigning the document.  If the result is nothing then the document is not open.  e.g. set wDoc = wd.Documents(Dokname); If wdoc is nothing then.....

Comment: Sorry. you will need an on Error resume next before the set statement.

Comment: Is the first document it checks the file name you're checking for? If yes, then it will exit the loop because that's what you're telling the code to do - as a matter of fact, you're telling it to leave the entire *FUNCTION* (`Exit Function`). I assume you meant `Exit For` so that it will leave just the loop...

Comment: When I try to check with `wd.Documents.Count` the result is 1, even tho two Word applications are open. @Freeflow greate idea, but it does not work for me. I think its bc there is only one Document in the wd obj. @Cindy Meister, the Exit Function is working for my case, bc if the doc is open I return true and exit the function bc the name of all other doc are not important for me.

So my theses is, that there is an word app for every doc. Is there a way to get all app's in one obj vba to check? 
maybe i am wrong to.. not sure for anything anymore.

Comment: If your host application is Word then you don't need to create another word application e.g. the WD object in the first code example.

Comment: But if i check the count of the wd obj after setting it with the getObject() methode, there is only one document in there, for this one document the first code i posted workes out well, but the second word document that is open gets ignored. So if i check for the second document, the code will return false. Im don't want a second wd obj if it's not necessary, but i think windows makes creates an second application for this document. Also there are two open Word tasks in the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

this one works - finally, took me hours to find the solution.

```vb
Function FileInWordOpen(DokName As String) As Boolean
Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Long, s As String
On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
If wd Is Nothing Then
    FileInWordOpen = False
End If
For i = 1 To wd.Documents.Count
    s = wd.Documents(i)
    If InStr(DokName, s) <> 0 Then
        FileInWordOpen = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

'For Each wDoc In wd.Documents        'should check for every open word file but doesn't do that
'    If wDoc.Name = DokName Then      'checks if this file is named like the one I want to check if its open or not
'        FileInWdOpen = True
'        Exit Function
'    End If
'Next

NO_WORD_FOUND:
    FileInWordOpen = False

End Function


Function GetOpenWordDoc(DokName As String) As Word.Document
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo NO_WORD_FOUND
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set GetOpenWordDoc = Nothing
    End If
    For i = 1 To wd.Documents.Count
        s = wd.Documents(i)
        If InStr(DokName, s) <> 0 Then
            Set GetOpenWordDoc = wd.Documents(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

NO_WORD_FOUND:
    Set GetOpenWordDoc = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP code works perfectly for me. If you want to check within the running instance of Word, calling the `GetObject` function is superfluous, as the global variable `Application` is a reference to the running instance. You can then use one of the following two functions, the second of which takes up the idea of freeflow. I prefer to use the `FullName` property instead of the `Name` property, the second function only works with this property. The `FullName` property returns the fully qualified name of the document, the `Name` property only returns the name of the file but omits the path to the directory.

```
Function FileInWordOpen(FullDocName As String) As Boolean
  
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document
  FileInWordOpen = False
  
  For Each wDoc In Application.Documents
   
    If (wDoc.FullName = FullDocName) Then
      FileInWordOpen = True
      Exit Function
    End If
    
  Next

End Function

Function FileInWordOpen1(FullDocName As String) As Boolean
  
  FileInWordOpen1 = False
  
  On Error GoTo Err
  If Not (Application.Documents(FullDocName) Is Nothing) Then
    FileInWordOpen1 = True
    Exit Function
  End If
  
Err: FileInWordOpen1 = False
End Function
```